# How do I place threads at the top(bump) based on last user post?

Tags: mysql, sql, forum, posting

http://www.vidyasocks.com/requests.php

I want it so when I post in a thread it will bump that thread to the top.

This is what I currently have for the page`"SELECT * from forum ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 12";`

The database has thread with an id(pk) and replies with a id(pk) and a thread_id(fk)

What do I do? Some kind of inner join I'd assume?

Comment: `:)` @ scrolltext. That should be `you're too slow` (apostrophe in contracted you-are, too instead of to).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have a date/timestamp for when threads and replies are inserted? You can't just order based on reply ID because there are threads without any reply and it isn't possible to correlate thread_id order with the reply id order.

If I have the right idea for your table structure you'd be doing something like this given some timestamps:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT forum.* FROM forum 
      LEFT JOIN replies on
          forum.id = replies.thread_id
  ORDER BY coalesce(replies.reply_timestamp, forum.thread_timestamp) DESC
    LIMIT 12
```

The coalesce would return replies.reply_timestamp if a reply exists otherwise the forum.thread_timestamp would be used.

**edit:** added DISTINCT based on Ami's comment

Comment: With nulls coming last that would put all threads without a reply (null reply_timestamp) at the bottom regardless of their thread_timestamp value. The group of threads without a reply would then be sorted by their thread_timestamp but they still won't be ordered within the group of reply_timestamp rows.

Comment: @nvuono, you're absolutely right. I withdraw my suggestion. :) It sucks that we have to live with the coalesce.